# multiple if statements cpp

Tags: c++, if-statement

I don't like having a lot of if-statements. Is there anyway that make an If-statement that allows the int to be equal to multiple numbers and then execute the statement if any one of those numbers are entered?

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {
        int year;

        cin>>year;
        //Rat
     if (year==2008) 
     cout<<"The year "<< year <<" is the year of the Rat";

     if (year==1996)
     cout<<"The year "<< year <<" is the year of the Rat";

     if (year==1984)
     cout<<"The year "<< year <<" is the year of the Rat";

     if (year==1972)
     cout<<"The year "<< year <<" is the year of the Rat";




     //Error message
    if (year<1964)
    cout<<"Please enter a valid number.";

    if (year>2018)
    cout<<"Please enter a valid number.";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

Comment: A condition with the or (`||`) operator?

Comment: `if (year == 2006 || year == 1994 || ...)`

Comment: You can also use arithmetic: `if (year % 12 == 2)`

Comment: maybe a switch/case?

Comment: Not related to programming but saying that 1994 is the year of the Rat is wrong. Not only is the year of the Rat 1996 instead of 1994 but the Chinese new year usually isn't until late January - mid February so there's a full month or so of the previous year.

Answer (score 5):

The year of the rat occurs every 12th year, so you can use:

```
if(year % 12 == 2) {
    cout << "The year " << year << " is the year of the Rat" << endl;
}
```

You'll just have to make sure to do your range checking (`if (year<1964)`...) before this, since this won't care about how early or late the date is.

---

**However**, a quick google search shows the year of the rat is actually 1972, 1984, 1996... so while my above code is a valid shortening of the code you've posted, the *correct* code should be:

```
if(year % 12 == 4) {
    cout << "The year " << year << " is the year of the Rat" << endl;
}
```

If we wanted to generalize to all zodiac animals, we can do so easily using mod and an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> zodiac_animals = {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Goat"};
cout << "The year " << year << " is the year of the " << zodiac_animals.at(year%12) << endl;
```

Comment: Or you can change the text to "year of the Dog". Equally correct. This year (2018) is year of the Dog indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a logical operator:

```
if (year == 2008 || year == 1996 || year == 1984 || year == 1972)
```

You can also use `switch/case` and take advantage of the fallthrough behavior when you don't use `break` between cases:

```
switch (year) {
case 2008:
case 1996:
case 1984:
case 1972:
    cout >> "The year " << year << " is the year of the Rat" << endl;
    break;
    ...
}
```

But the simplest way is to take advantage of the 12-year cycle in the Chinese Zodiac to do this with arithmetic and a vector, so you don't have to list years explicitly (with the possibility of getting the years wrong, as you did).

```
const std::vector<const std::string> zodiac {"Monkey", "Rooster", "Dog", "Pig", "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon"< "Snake", "Horse", "Goat"};
cin >> year;
cout << "The year " << year << " is the year of the " << zodiac[year % zodiac.size()] << '\n';
```

Comment: First you beat me by 40 seconds with your comment and then by a few minutes with your vector implementation. You're in my head! Should I edit out my vector implementation since you posted yours first? I wouldn't want it to seem like I'm taking your ideas...

Comment: Don't worry about it. If we were editing at the same time, they're both valid.

Answer (score 0):

If your set of data you want to check against is finite and you really want to minimize all kinds of branching structure, you could always use a container and an `std::algorithm` like `find`. Here is an example (you can read more on it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; // finite set of values
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints + 4);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  it = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 30);
  if (it != myvector.end()) // Only one if
    std::cout << "Element found in myvector: " << *it << '\n';
  else
    std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This will always boil down to a call to `std::find` (or any other algorithm, depending on your case) and one `if`.